# Generify classes that reference themselves

Tags: c#, generics

Is there any way to generify this two classes?

```
class Tag1{
  public Tag1 Parent{get;set;}
}

class Tag2{
  public Tag2 Parent{get;set;}
}
```

So I will have:

```
class Tag1 : Tag{}

class Tag2 : Tag{}
```

Seems no, but possible that I missed something global.

Thanks to Jon, I ended with the following solution:

```
class Tag1 : Tag<T> {
   public T Parent {get;set;}

  public T AddNew(){
      return new T(){Parent = (T)this;} // This works
  }
}
```

Comment: Either a definition of 'generificate', or a quick run through a spell checker, is required before I could offer any kind of answer...

Comment: heh... coining a new term, I see.

Comment: Do you mean make generic?  As in make the class that references itself a generic class?

Comment: @jrista: I assume he means "make use generics"

Comment: I believe he wants it to accept be in generics, something like Tag1<TType>

Comment: What exactly do you want to make generic? A property of Parent? The type itself?

Comment: Yeh, "make use generics" or "generify" (from IntelliJ IDEA) my mistake :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, slightly messier than before, and the subclass needs to do a bit more work, but...

```
public abstract class SelfRef<T> where T : SelfRef<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> childFactory;

    public T Parent { get; set; }

    protected SelfRef(Func<T> childFactory)
    {
        this.childFactory = childFactory;
    }

    public T AddNew()
    {
       return childFactory();
    }
}

public sealed class Ref1 : SelfRef<Ref1>
{
    public Ref1()
        : base(() => new Ref1 { Parent = this })
    {            
    }
}
```

I think that meets the requirements. Note that you'll always have trouble implementing a hierarchy more than one level deep under `SelfRef` however you do it, so don't bother :)

You could potentially make the child factory take the new parent. Basically the type relationship you really want - that `T = (the same type deriving from SelfRef<T>)` - can't be expressed in .NET generics, which is why you have a slight mess.

Comment: How would you instantiate that with a self-reference? First<First<First<...>, Second<...>>, Second<Second<Second<...>>>>?

Comment: jrista I do not need instantiation, but the problem with this solution is that Tagged<T> cannnot create instances of the same type. I forgot to add this requirment to questtion.

Comment: Damn, evening, need coffee! Thanks Jon!

Comment: Ah yes. Okay - will take a look later. I suspect the subclass needs to pass in a function to create a new instance appropriately.

Comment: @Skeet & Mike: My original comment was for the version of this post before it was edited...I posted an answer, then deleted it once I realized the recursion problem. I'm intrigued by the current version of this answer...does it actually solve the problem you were having Mike? (I've had similar problems myself in the past...never solved them...)

Comment: Yep, this fully resolved my problem. I ended with simple casting in Add method. So Parent = (T)this. And this works for me. Of course, solution with delegate looks great, but cast is just simplier :).

Comment: @Mike: Yup - the cast should be fine, so long as your subclasses are sensible. And I agree that if you can get away with it, it's simpler :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you help me understand why http://stackoverflow.com/a/25044956/55721 doesn't work for this situation. Maybe I'm not understanding the requirement.

Comment: @dss539: There was a "hidden" requirement in the question for the top type to create instances of itself. It's possible that `where T : new()` would have worked for that too. I can't remember back this long...

Answer (score 0):

Heh... my first thought was this:

```
public class ParentizedClass<T>
{
   public T Parent {get; set;}
}
```

But then I thought... "no, that can't work."

I don't believe it's possible.

Hmm... working on it some more, you could use an interface:

```
public interface ParentizedClass<T>
{
   public T Parent {get; set;}
}
```

And then have the class implement the interface using itself as the base class:

```
public class MyClass : ParentizedClass<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass Parent {get; set;}
}
```

But I can't check that for validity at the moment.

Comment: Because you can't declare an instance of it.

var obj = new ParentizedClass<ParentizedClass<ParentizedClass<...>>>();

Comment: Because the parent is not the same type as the original class. The parent is of type T while the original class is of type ParentizedClass<T>. He wants the parent to be the same type as the original class, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: Right - it doesn't answer the question, but the code presented was valid.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class Tag<T>
{
    public Tag<T> Parent{get; set;}
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice hairy example:

```
  class Pair<TCar, TCdr>
  {
    public TCar Car { get; set; }
    public TCdr Cdr { get; set; }
  }

  class List<T> : Pair<T, List<T>>, IEnumerable<T>
  {
    public List(T car, List<T> cdr)
    {
      Car = car;
      Cdr = cdr;
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
      yield return Car;
      var cdr = Cdr;
      while (cdr != null)
      {
        yield return cdr.Car;
        cdr = cdr.Cdr;
      }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, though I'm not sure I understand the question, and it's been a long time since you asked it.

```
class Child<T> where T : Child<T> { public T Parent { get; set; } }
class Tag : Child<Tag> { }
class Tag1 : Tag { }
class Tag2 : Tag { }
```